# Chained conversion between classes without public inheritances

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion

**Question**

I have a series of ~10 template classes A, B, C, D, ...

I want to enable conversions from a class to previous classes in the series:

- D -> C, B, or A
- C -> B, or A
- B -> A

How to make that happen without using public inheritance?

---

**Test 1** (public inheritance)

- I don't want inheritance of public methods.

---

**Test 2** (define 1 + 2 + ... n conversion operators):

- Define n conversion operators for the nth template class
  template class.
- Very tedious

---

**Test 3** (1 conversion operator per class):

- only allow conversion from a type of next level to a type of this level.

For example, that enables conversion from D to C, but not from D to B.

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'template+%3Ctypename+Convertible%3E%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++operator+Convertible()+%7B+return+Convertible()%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ausing+B+%3D+A%3Cint%3E%3B%0Ausing+C+%3D+A%3CB%3E%3B%0Ausing+D+%3D+A%3CC%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++D+d%3B%0A++++auto+b+%3D+B(d)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.154046997389045,l:'4',m:71.89249720044792,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',m:48.99103139013454,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:51.00896860986548,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.84595300261096,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
template <typename Convertible>
class A {
public:
    operator Convertible() { return Convertible(); }
};

using B = A<int>;
using C = A<B>;
using D = A<C>;

int main() {
    D d;
    auto b = B(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A<int>::A(D&)’
     auto b = B(d);
                 ^
```

---

**Actual use case**

A, B, C, D ... are each nodes (proxies) created by a layer of an object S.

- Type 1 layers define memory organization of nodes of a graph
  (pointer/array).
- Type 2 layers convert a layer to another container. (e.g. layer with a hash for indexing nodes by keys and tracking swapping of nodes.)

User can stack the layers in many ways to create the object S.

I want nodes of one layer to convert to nodes of previous layers.

This is possible because the pointer to/index of the content of the nodes would be the same.

Comment: C++ can't automatically figure out how to do type conversion all by itself. A subclass can be converted to its superclass, or a conversion operator must be defined. That's it. There are no further options. When two classes are completely unrelated, C++ can't just automatically figure out how to convert one to another.

Comment: So... I should enable universal conversion and then constraint conversion with traits?

Comment: Just curious to know what could be the use case of this chained type conversion

Comment: Well, just because you say that A is convertible to B, it doesn't mean that the compiler can figure out how to do it. You have to spell out how A is converted to B. Whatever the case may be, either via a method call, by fetching A's class member, or whatever. It's impossible to say without seeing specific, concrete examples. I don't know what "universal conversion" means. And this does [look like an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: conversion operator to any type: `template <typename T>
    operator T() { return T(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @hlt's approach will do what you ask, without knowing more about the context, I'm wary about implementing the conversion in `A`. In the cases I can think of, `A` shouldn't be aware of `B`, `C` or `D`, so I'll suggest a different implementation.

You can create a variant of your test 3, where you implement one conversion operator per class, *but* where you also inherit a templated indirect conversion operator, like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct indirect_conversion {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, T2>>>
    operator T() {
        return static_cast<T1 *>(this)->operator T2();
    }
};

struct A {};

struct B : indirect_conversion<B, A> {
    operator A();
};
struct C : indirect_conversion<C, B> {
    operator B();
};
struct D : indirect_conversion<D, C> {
    operator C();
};
A a = D();
```

Comment: @Rzu It does compile, it just doesn't link, because I haven't provided definitions for `B::operator A`, `C::operator B` and `D::operator C`. You'll have to figure out something sensible for them to do. Simply returning `A()`/`B()`/`C()` as you did will work for demo purposes, but probably only for demo purposes.

Comment: This really converts from D to C, C to B, and finally B to A! Thanks.

Comment: @Rzu It should work fine for templates too. If you share your non-working attempt, I can take a look to see what's wrong. I can't quite tell if your last sentence is about the whole of the rest of your comment and if you got it working already.

Comment: I made a simple type system with this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194326/type-system-for-layers-and-nodes

Comment: Is `is_convertible` better than `is_constructible` in this case? https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/is-constructible/

Comment: @Rzu It probably is. I'm not sure why I went with `is_constructible`; what `is_convertible` checks is much closer to what I'm actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by constraining a templated constructor (which will be used in conversion) using `std::enable_if` and some template metaprogramming:

```
template <template <class> typename BaseTemplate,
          typename From,
          typename To,
          typename Enable = void>
struct may_convert
    : public std::false_type {};

template <template <class> typename BaseTemplate,
          typename T>
struct may_convert<BaseTemplate, BaseTemplate<T>, BaseTemplate<T>, void>
    : public std::true_type {};

template <template <class> typename BaseTemplate,
          typename T,
          typename U>
struct may_convert<BaseTemplate, BaseTemplate<T>, BaseTemplate<U>, 
                   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, U>::value>::type>
    : public may_convert<BaseTemplate, T, BaseTemplate<U>> {};
```

`may_convert` will walk up the templates of the `From` template parameter until it is equal to `To` (in which case it inherits from `std::true_type`, i.e. `may_convert<...>::value` is `true`), or until the templates run out (in which case `may_convert<...>::value` is `false`).

Now, all that remains is constraining your constructor appropriately:

```
template <typename Convertible>
class A {
public:
    A() {}

    template <typename T,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                  may_convert<A, T, A<Convertible>>::value>::type>
    A(const T&) {}
};
```

This way, the constructor exists only if `may_convert<...>::value` is `true`. Otherwise, the conversion will fail.

---

#### Examples

Here is an example of how `may_convert` works in your example (converting from `D = A<A<A<int>>>` to `B = A<int>`):

- The constructor only exists if `may_convert<A, D, B>::value` is `true`
- `may_convert<A, D, B>` matches the last specialization (because `D = A<C>` and `B = A<int>`, the parameters are deduced as `T = C` and `U = int`) and inherits from `may_convert<A, C, B>`
- `may_convert<A, C, B>` again matches the last specialization (`T = B`, `U = int`) and inherits from `may_convert<A, B, B>`
- This time, the two types are equal, so the first specialization matches, and the entire thing inherits from `std::true_type`, enabling the constructor.

On the other hand, imagine a `using E = A<double>` that should not convert to `B`:

- The constructor will only be enabled if `may_convert<A, E, B>::value` is `true`
- `may_convert<A, E, B>` matches the last specialization, and inherits from `may_convert<A, double, B>`
- Because `double` is not an `A<...>`, none of the specializations match, so we fall back to the default case, which inherits from `std::false_type`.
- Therefore, `may_convert<A, E, B>::value` is `false`, and the conversion fails.

Comment: I probably will use a `static_assert` for `may_convert` within the conversion operator. That way I can add an error message for the user. Thanks.