# Doubly chained conversions between classes

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion, multiple-inheritance

I have a series of classes A, B, C, ...

I want to define conversion between any pair of classes.

The conversion has to follow the ordering of classes in the series.

---

For example, a conversions from A to C has the following steps:

1. A converts to B.
2. B finally converts to C

---

Similarly, a conversion from C to A has the following steps:

1. C to B
2. B to A

---

I try to modify the answer of my last question:

[Chained conversion between classes without public inheritances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307311/chained-conversion-between-classes-without-public-inheritances)

But I can only get chained conversion from C to A work. 
Chained conversions in the opposite direction doesn't work.

> How to make chained conversions in both directions work?

Test (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgQCeAB0wB9AsSaFBG7BwAMAQTkKlKzOq15Ugk5iYBbSzdsCTB89ZiDXbX1MFl8XABV6VV0DGJ94rn87T2IRZAJVNBYAN0xiQXcWQ2QEMxZ1AHY%2BO1UWpODQpnCNSJTY1TjSJKjUlw0AEVVPdBAQaKYAIwYjPAAzY26A1q3tqZm8QSrUFmzcgjxFoyLugf6M2Stm1v97zdbUA1MiYn6IAEoGpq2batYiYAhiOqeTp4ZBVJiea60VQAKksEAICH2vwAtJZ3qVOiRbn8NICthx6mMAhSqbJAQETnlVHw6QyTKdVJpSdSsuymUCKTxVPjPkSeCS6Q1afTeTkmUKQAUjiUyhUqjUFN0BKp7PdBoUVeUjuralrBlz7gDXi0RYTvrYJWS3h87ZzHdTKdzZRzNKpFQbSkbKtVTVpNIMWdgrY8bS6vsz3XYaV77HZbDNbfHxf9BdbJgRpihRPkNlp1FwuEDcZa%2BABWTQsbh3J0tUHg4h1bMp5NJuw8DNxokOnONPO7IsiEtabrl3iqatR%2Bz1xsVlNbNsQnWJ%2Bye3u2fsgTNEzR/aNA1rjtCTiIzptChecjjLptrkFgzcn37d3ep3%2BaAcElmp65jG%2BaFleU4Wr6Ta%2Bg%2BdYNi%2BrKgRuHYJl%2BSE7lSe4KPkPi1MBo6gUCTCuBMn6vi0vrIKRW7oUKqgAPQMf0mKCKoDAKC46CoJgbEsKg%2BRoCEeBLAAdHmKF1NY35jFIvyMNItZSKQLDSNYymoNIXK8PwkyiOIoxcLItDKQQalyfJADWIC1lwom0LWAAs1iOQAbAAnO59SyAAHO5Lm1gpUiOcpPggPUtCiX5XCOV5XDWC5jn1O5XAqeZpCaVIymCCA1ikGZUjqfJcCwDAiBFsJSxkBQEBCXoImlCAwDeaQKwiUEZSUPM6XzAoTDEDo6VCWkLAEAA8iwDCDYVylYHhbBLOl%2BCgnkeAlDlM2kJgAAemDIJOkhSCZ5CjZgDDSMdJh4GFM3ycwbAoPw/CMOcOWQPJ7xnEcG3YlM4ycDpvC0PU2X6RIdB3YpymqZtmXbT5rnYq5jmqMAyDUfUomyKoEC4IQRJyIkmioJVpTlsZ/zaXwvCmeZvzyQg3hYMQlBWTZeXncFoUgK5kUI8jFbWK5PlcA5PlpbD0jZbl%2BV06QJXlcWeiTuQlB1Q1LP0Jg%2BBfHQpAAO6mHocuc0pEvqRl0iE6o%2BuEAgqjw4jyOo%2BjqiY7ItO3QzTONX8QUhaQYW%2BfZsiyLW9TJcZ9Q%2BY5ovmxpUtCDLBVFWzSVRY5tbubWsgJVwvPWO5rlBR78eW1lste0FXDQ%2BlmWe6npCGhUICOUAA))

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct conversion_chain {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_constructible_v<T, T2>
    >>
    operator T() {
        return static_cast<T1 *>(this)->operator T2();
    }
};

struct B;
struct C;

struct A { operator B(); };

struct B : conversion_chain<B, A>, conversion_chain<B, C> {
    operator A();
    operator C();
};
struct C : conversion_chain<C, B> {
    operator B();
};

A::operator B() {
    std::cout << "A -> B\n";
    return B();
}

B::operator A() {
    std::cout << "B -> A\n";
    return A();
}

B::operator C() {
    std::cout << "B -> C\n";
    return C();
}


C::operator B() {
    std::cout << "C -> B\n";
    return B();
}

int main() {
    A a = C();
    C c = A();  // This line does not compile.
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
<source>:49:11: error: conversion from 'A' to non-scalar type 'C' requested

     C c = A();  // This line does not compile.

           ^~~
```

Comment: Have you tried inheriting `A` from `conversion_chain`?

Answer (score 0):

Fix by making `A` inherits from `conversion_chain`:

```
struct A : conversion_chain<A, B> { operator B(); };
```