# Simplifying Doubly Chained Conversions

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion

**Question**

I want conversions between classes A, B, C, D, E.

Conversion should happen step-wise.

For example, conversion from A to E involves conversions A->B->C->D->E.

Conversion from E to B involves conversions E->D->C->B

I tried to simplified the answer at:

[Doubly chained conversions between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309378/doubly-chained-conversions-between-classes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it doesn't compile now.

- Why it worked before and doesn't work now?
- Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks again.

---

**Test** (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgQCeAB0wB9AsSaFBG7BwAMAQTkKlKzOq15Ugk5iYBbSzfs7AkwfPWZgjW19TBZfFwBlTAYAM387T2IRZAJVZAQzFkM0FgA3TGJg4nUAdj47VQbVYNDwzEjdA1ifFwB5AgRy0iborpcNABFVT3QQEBimACMGIzxk40iAxq3t6dm8QSLUFgysgjwloxLIxJShvoHiNNst/1kresbUA1MiKvvyiAAShqdWe2waxEwBDELCmBCYZ2QRSYnmuSWSACpLBB%2BvtAQBaSxfcoIkiqf7EIEaUEvarjAIcOnUhnpEynVR8WSgk7ZVSaZl2AI8nLPEC5fIKQ6lcqVSL2N4g1TEn5knhUrk1elclm2YUc1RivIFKVlCrlSKc7Agzafb6kqq2dWgm0NZX2vlOhlM7WC1mZXmaA3i43FU2yrT8hWMnhKu2/DlOzUCwK2WyzN3xtXA6OqSHQ4iwrPUpO%2B2w8dNxsmO7O1XNQmGqavFxn00vlkAZsmaIGKvMN7uA5tM0uaCskzM9nN9gsJwcals6hQ5HwFSe1F1wmYoUQ5DZaTd7A7FYXnZaGK5aASNyyuSOB7hcDgAVk0LAfya2zyYrkmA4/jUDZAf0bT0PghesZ2sZMFzsKRAUYaQnykUgWGkaxkNQaR%2BV4fgplEcQxi4WRaGQgg0Lg%2BCAGsQCfLgADpaCfAAWawmIANgATg46pZAADg41inwQqQmOQnwQGqWg6P4rgmO4rhrFYpjqg4rgUPI0hMKkZDBBAaxSDIqR0PguBYBgRBt1CPBljICgIDQKybJAYAeNIZJrMqXSIAWDSFgUJhiB0DSHO6FgCB6FgGCCozkKwFc2GWDT8EhbI8DKXSYtITAAA9MGQERgmkEjyDCpIitI4g8HEmL4OYNgUH4fhGHOXTIHgr4ziODL8WmCZOBw3haGqHT8IkOhasQ5DUMyrTst4tj8TYpjVGAZAgOqOjZFUCBcEIMk5HoPlUEc8p1CI2hgWwvheFI8jAXggYmCwYhKComj9IYaRRNIcS2Kk%2Balq4BS2N4rhGN49SZukHS9IMu7SFMiydz0AryEoBy9Gs8o6Cy/BfhxgB3Uw9Hhz6pCQyH0M06QDtUAnCAQVQ5oWpbcjq4BVDYujrG526aoe7xnte4TvvEviGNkWQn2qFTiOqXimLBymMOhoRYcM4y3uU6SmKfDin1kRSuD%2B6wOLY4TZCmjStL5zXhK4K2oe0uH%2BdIU1BHcVCmKAA%3D%3D))

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Self>
struct chain_converter {
    template<typename Other, typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_constructible_v<Self, Other>
    >>
    operator Other() {
        return static_cast<Self*>(this)->operator Other();
    }
};

struct B;
struct C;

struct A : chain_converter<A> { operator B(); };    
struct B : chain_converter<B> {
    operator A();    
    operator C();
};    
struct C : chain_converter<C> { operator B(); };

A::operator B() { return B(); }    
B::operator A() { return A(); }    
B::operator C() { return C(); }    
C::operator B() { return B(); }

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_constructible_v<B, A> 
              << "\n";
    A a = C();
    C c = A();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler Error** (from [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgQCeAB0wB9AsSaFBG7BwAMAQTkKlKzOq15Ugk5iYBbSzfs7AkwfPWZgjW19TBZfFwBlTAYAM387T2IRZAJVZAQzFkM0FgA3TGJg4nUAdj47VQbVYNDwzEjdA1ifFwB5AgRy0iborpcNABFVT3QQEBimACMGIzxk40iAxq3t6dm8QSLUFgysgjwloxLIxJShvoHiNNst/1kresbUA1MiKvvyiAAShqdWe2waxEwBDELCmBCYZ2QRSYnmuSWSACpLBB%2BvtAQBaSxfcoIkiqf7EIEaUEvarjAIcOnUhnpEynVR8WSgk7ZVSaZl2AI8nLPEC5fIKQ6lcqVSL2N4g1TEn5knhUrk1elclm2YUc1RivIFKVlCrlSKc7Agzafb6kqq2dWgm0NZX2vlOhlM7WC1mZXmaA3i43FU2yrT8hWMnhKu2/DlOzUCwK2WyzN3xtXA6OqSHQ4iwrPUpO%2B2w8dNxsmO7O1XNQmGqavFxn00vlkAZsmaIGKvMN7uA5tM0uaCskzM9nN9gsJwcals6hQ5HwFSe1F1wmYoUQ5DZaTd7A7FYXnZaGK5aASNyyuSOB7hcDgAVk0LAfya2zyYrkmA4/jUDZAf0bT0PghesZ2sZMFzsKRAUYaQnykUgWGkaxkNQaR%2BV4fgplEcQxi4WRaGQgg0Lg%2BCAGsQCfLgADpaCfAAWawmIANgATg46pZAADg41inwQqQmOQnwQGqWg6P4rgmO4rhrFYpjqg4rgUPI0hMKkZDBBAaxSDIqR0PguBYBgRBt1CPBljICgIDQKybJAYAeNIZJrMqXSIAWDSFgUJhiB0DSHO6FgCB6FgGCCozkKwFc2GWDT8EhbI8DKXSYtITAAA9MGQERgmkEjyDCpIitI4g8HEmL4OYNgUH4fhGHOXTIHgr4ziODL8WmCZOBw3haGqHT8IkOhasQ5DUMyrTst4tj8TYpjVGAZAgOqOjZFUCBcEIMk5HoPlUEc8p1CI2hgWwvheFI8jAXggYmCwYhKComj9IYaRRNIcS2Kk%2Balq4BS2N4rhGN49SZukHS9IMu7SFMiydz0AryEoBy9Gs8o6Cy/BfhxgB3Uw9Hhz6pCQyH0M06QDtUAnCAQVQ5oWpbcjq4BVDYujrG526aoe7xnte4TvvEviGNkWQn2qFTiOqXimLBymMOhoRYcM4y3uU6SmKfDin1kRSuD%2B6wOLY4TZCmjStL5zXhK4K2oe0uH%2BdIU1BHcVCmKAA%3D%3D)):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:37:11: error: conversion from 'C' to non-scalar type 'A' requested

     A a = C();

           ^~~

<source>:38:11: error: conversion from 'A' to non-scalar type 'C' requested

     C c = A();

           ^~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

---

**Previous code that works** (also at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aadf96379ee9da63)):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct indirect_conversion {
    template <typename T, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t<
                  std::is_constructible_v<T, T2>
              >
    >
    operator T() {
        return static_cast<T1 *>(this)->operator T2();
    }
};

struct A {};

struct B : indirect_conversion<B, A> {
    operator A() {
        std::cout << "B -> A\n";
        return A();
    }
};
struct C : indirect_conversion<C, B> {
    operator B() {
        std::cout << "C -> B\n";
        return B();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a = C();
}
```

**Result:**

```
C -> B
B -> A
```

Comment: What kind of application needs such strange conversions?

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is not a useful description. *How* does it not work? Does it not compile? If so, is there a diagnostic message? If so, what does it say? Does it compile, but behaves wrong? How does it behave? What did you expect?

Comment: @RSahu: It is for a library for objects with multiple layers, and conversion between proxies to each layer. For use case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307311/chained-conversion-between-classes-without-public-inheritances

Comment: @Rzu does the compiler not show a diagnostic message?

Comment: This doesn't work for templated classes `A<T1>`, `B<T2>`, `C<T3>`. Only inheritance works. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion is only allowed once when considering the argument to a constructor or to a user-defined conversion function.
[Implicit conversions - Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)
As for the previous code, the reason C can convert to A because struct C inherits conversion_chain, and I add a little change here to help understand:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct conversion_chain {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_constructible_v<T, T2>
        >>
        operator T() {
        cout << "cnoversion from " << typeid(T1).name() << " to " << typeid(T).name() << " via " << typeid(T2).name() << " as below." << endl;
        return static_cast<T1 *>(this)->operator T2();
    }
};
```

And I remember "Inside Cpp Object Model" has said implicit conversion invoked automatically by compiler is allowed only once, but explicit conversion like "A.operator B()" has no limits on invoke times if it can compile correctly.

Comment: Cppreference mention one unambiguous conversion *sequence*. Can that sequence contain multiple conversions between types?

Comment: @Rzu between some types, yes. But at most one conversion that involves user defined types (i.e. classes).

Comment: Chained conversion works in the original code. Is that because the `indirect_conversion`'s conversion operator requests an explicit conversion? If that is the case, both the original and the simplified code do that.

Comment: @Rzu the compiler deduces operator T() in template conversion_chain, and I make [a little change here](https://pastebin.com/MFMaQ7sf)

Comment: @Rzu explicit conversion invocation has no limit, but implicit conversion automatically by compiler is only allowed once, which I remember in <<Inside Cpp Object Model>>

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  error: conversion from 'C' to non-scalar type 'A' requested
> ```

This error simply tells you that `C` is not convertible to `A`.

It is not convertible because there is neither a conversion `operator A()` in `C`, nor is there a converting constructor `A(const C&)` in `A`.

You may have intended the conversion operator to be inherited from `chain_converter<C>` as it was inherited in the working version, but that base does not in fact have such conversion operator, because the template argument substitution of `std::enable_if_t` fails. The substitution fails because `std::is_constructible_v<C, A>` is false. It is false, because `C` cannot be constructed with an `A` argument.

---

Your "simplification" of the working code cannot work. The second template argument of `chain_converter` is essential.

Comment: @Rzu yes there is. The operator is inherited from `indirect_conversion<C, B>`. It is a template operator that can convert to any type (as long as the template argument substitution succeeds; and the substitution only succeeds when `B` is convertible to that type).

Comment: @Rzu `using` is unnecessary for a conversion operator. What you need is for `chain_converter` to have a conversion operator whose template substitution succeeds. The difference is that in the "simplified" the substitution fails, and in the working code it doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

After adding code to pin-point the conversions in the original code, I get the following:

**Result**:

```
Template conversion
    is_constructible<1A, 1C>
    call non-template conversion: 1D->1C
    return a 1C as a 1A
Non-template conversion: D -> C
Template conversion
    is_constructible<1A, 1B>
    call non-template conversion: 1C->1B
    return a 1B as a 1A
Non-template conversion: C -> B
Non-template conversion: B -> A
```

**Step 1**:

After manually moving the code from `indirect_conversion` to struct `D`, I get the following:

```
struct D {
    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_constructible_v<T, C>
    >>
    operator T() {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->operator C();
    }
....
```

The main function requests implicit conversion from `D` to `A`.

*Assume* `C` is constructible from `A`.

Because `C` is constructible from `A`, enable implicit conversion operator from `D` to `A`.

Define the implicit conversion from `D` to `A` as:

- Explicitly converts from `D` to `C` by `static_cast<D*>(this)->operator C();`.

  - This is the `Non-template: D -> C` in the result.
- Request implicit conversion from `C` to `A`

  - It requests the implicit conversion because the return statement returns a `C` but the return type `T` is `A`.

The rest of the steps are similar.

**Explanation of the assumption**

The last section explains the 1st step. All of the steps together explain the initial assumption that `C` is constructible from `A`.

`B` is constructible from `A`. That means:

- Conversion operator from `C` to `A` is enabled. That means `C` is constructible from `A`.

  - That means Conversion operator from `D` to `A` is enabled. That means `D` is constructible from `A`.

**The modified code for testing**:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct indirect_conversion {
    template <typename T,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<
                    std::is_constructible_v<T, T2>
            >
    >
    operator T() {
        auto T_name = typeid(T).name();
        auto T1_name = typeid(T1).name();
        auto T2_name = typeid(T2).name();
        std::cout << "Template conversion" << "\n";
        std::cout << "    is_constructible<"
                  << T_name << ", "
                  << T2_name << ">\n";
        std::cout << "    call non-template conversion: "
                  << T1_name << "->" << T2_name << "\n";

        std::cout << "    return a " << T2_name << " as a " << T_name << "\n";
        return static_cast<T1 *>(this)->operator T2();
    }
};

struct A {};

struct B : indirect_conversion<B, A> {
    operator A() {
        std::cout << "Non-template conversion: B -> A\n";
        return A();
    }
};
struct C : indirect_conversion<C, B> {
    operator B() {
        std::cout << "Non-template conversion: C -> B\n";
        return B();
    }
};

struct D : indirect_conversion<D, C> {
    operator C() {
        std::cout << "Non-template conversion: D -> C\n";
        return C();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a = D();
}
```